# How to insert data into 1-to-1 relationship tables in django

Tags: django, model

i'm new to django. I use django User and 2 extended tables (profile_table, more_table), each has a one-to-one relationship with User. So under models.py, i have 2 classes (one for profile_table, the other one for more_table). When I create a new user, i'll insert basic data into auth_user table and other information into profile_talbe and more_table. How and where to build this insert method? Should i use class manager? or overrite save function? or create a class method under profile_table class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create new instance from the profile model you should write static method in the profile model class.
Example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   @staticmethod
   def create_profile(name=name):
        profile = Profile(name=name)
        profile.save()

        return profile
```